# Trying to understand how to respond to CORS OPTIONS request with 403 and when

Tags: http, https, cors

I really want some validation after reading many websites on CORS to see if I have this

```
OPTIONS /frog/LOTS/upload/php.php HTTP/1.1
Host: staff.curriculum.local
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: http://frogserver.curriculum.local
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: cache-control,x-requested-with
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Here is when I think I respond with 403 ->

1. If my origin set on the server is not * and not that domain, I response with 403.
2. If I do not support POST (I may support GET), I respond with 403
3. If I do not support any ONE of the request headers, I respond with 403

For #1, if the domain is not supported, I will NOT send any Access Control headers in the response.  I think that is ok.

for #2 and #3, I would send these headers assuming Origin request header was a match

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://frogserver.curriculum.local
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: {exists and is true IF supported on server}
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {all request headers we support and not related to incoming 'Access-Control-Request-Headers' in the request}
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: {all methods supported NOT related to incoming method POST that came in?}
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: {all headers we allow browser origin website to read}
```

Is my assumption correct here? or are some of the response headers related to the request headers in some way I am not seeing?  (The names are similar but I don't think the behavior is tied to each other).

I would find it really odd that the request even needs to contain Access-Control-Request-Method & Access-Control-Request-Headers if we did not send back a 403 in the cases where we don't support all requested information on that endpoint, right?  This is why I 'suspect' we are supposed to return a 403 along with what we do support?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: You are never need to send a 403 back for an OPTIONS request.  For case 1, just don’t send back the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header at all; that will cause the OPTIONS preflight to fail in browsers, with a message saying, *“No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header”*. For case 2, just send back a Access-Control-Allow-Methods that doesn’t contain GET; that will cause the preflight to fail in browsers, with a message saying, *“GET is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight"*. For case 3, *“If I do not support any ONE of the request headers”* I don’t know what you mean.

Comment: The CORS protocol itself says nothing about when you’re supposed send back a 403. Most CORS libraries for most runtimes/programming languages do not ever send back a 403 for an OPTIONS preflight response. A 4xx error response is not necessary for a preflight to be unsuccessful. A preflight can be unsuccessful even when it has a 200 OK response — if the Access-Control-Allow-\* don’t allow it. If the Access-Control-Allow-\* headers don’t match, browsers don’t care what the status code is.

Comment: All that said, take a look at the language in the Fetch spec at https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-concept-status④, which says *“the 403 status can be used, coupled with omitting the relevant headers”* — but it explicitly doesn’t say the 403 *should* be used. And it ends that section by saying, *“Ultimately server developers have a lot of freedom in how they handle HTTP responses”* — so again, the spec avoids explicitly stating anything that you should do. So in the end, it’s up to you — though as I wrote in another comment, browsers don’t care, and most CORS libraries don’t send 403s.

Comment: Also: If you send a 403 without Access-Control-Allow-Origin, there’s no way frontend code can programmatically detect that the server responded with a 403 — because browsers will block frontend code from accessing the response’s HTTP status. All you’ll be able to see from frontend code is that a network error occurred — which is exactly the same as what frontend code would be limited to seeing if you omit Access-Control-Allow-Origin. In other words, a 403 response without Access-Control-Allow-Origin is programmatically indistinguishable from a 200 response without Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: @sideshowbarker *A 403 response [...] is programmatically indistinguishable from a 200 response [...].* That may be true of a preflight request, but it isn't true in general. See https://xsleaks.dev/docs/attacks/error-events/